# Cut food-low body fat to show more muscular

Tags: workout

I have cut food.In 3 days I have seen my abs more visisle but not more stronger.Anyway.If I am working out and eating proper healthy vegetables and fruits,protein(warning 1 meal food). Will my body show more muscular? Does this help grow more muscles?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of low food intake and working out is used for toning purposes to cut out extra body fat to make your muscles look more visible.

If you want to grow muscles you will need to do strength based workouts and increase your protein intake by eating protein rich foods to sustain muscle repair and growth and avoid foods high in fat and carbohydrates.

**Protein Rich Foods**

- Chicken
- Fish
- Lean Beef
- Eggs
- Beans

**Foods to avoid**

- Pasta (high in carbohydrates)
- Sugar (high in carbohydrates)
- Breads (high in carbohydrates)
- Deep Fried Foods (high in fat)
- Fruit Juices (high in sugar) best to stick with the whole fruit instead

Short Answer: Without sufficient protein intake your muscles will not grow no matter how much you are working out.

Comment: I eat 1 meal that include protein.

Comment: You need to increase your food intake. Think of yourself as a plant, for a plant to grow they need water(food) and sun(workout). A plant will not grow if it is only getting water and no sunlight, it will also not grow if it is only getting sunlight and no water. You need both for the plant to grow.